# Finding the spectrum of a C* algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I'm going through the topic of C$^*$-algebras and facing a few questions.

Q1. Consider the C$^*$-algebra $A=\bigoplus_{j=1}^n\mathbb C$ . What is the spectrum of $A$ (the collection of multiplicative non zero functionals) be?

I have tried to see $A$ as a direct sum but could not proceed further.

Answer (score 2):

This is an important "change of frame" that might help you: $$\mathbb C^n\simeq C(\{1,\ldots,n\}).$$
From there you can immediately see that the spectrum of $A$ is the discrete topological space with $n$ points (or $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, if you want).

For a way less exciting alternative, you can prove directly that if $\phi:\mathbb C^n\to\mathbb C$ is linear and multiplicative, then it is one of the coordinate maps. Namely, being linear forces $$\phi(a_1,\ldots ,a_n)=\sum_{j=1}^n \beta_ja_j$$ for some $\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_n\in\mathbb C$. Now, since $\phi$ is multiplicative, 
$$
\beta_1+\beta_2=\phi(1,1,\ldots,0)=\phi((1,1,\ldots,0)^2)=\phi(1,1,\ldots,0)^2=(\beta_1+\beta_2)^2, 
$$
from where you get that either $\beta_1=0$ or $\beta_2=0$. Now do the same between the surviving one and $\beta_3$, etc., to show that only one of the $\beta_j$ is nonzero.

Comment: I think your second approach is more elementary.  The first one requires verifying that every $*$-homomorphism $C(X)\to\mathbb C$ is evaluation at some point of $X$, which requires a proof that newcomers may may have not seen.

Comment: I still do not understand why either  B1 or B2 is 0.  A = C({1,2,...n}) 

Now, X = {1,2,..n} is compact and hausdorff with discrete topology.

Using the fact that Sp(C(X)) is homeomorphic to X.
Hence, |Sp(A)| = |X| = n. That's giving the dimension . So there the projections are the characters. But what Im getting the number of non trivial projection is more than than...how things are working here ?

Comment: Because $\beta_1\beta_2=0$. The rest, I don't know what you are talking about. Characters are linear functionals, so definitely not projections. The last three sentences I don't know what you mean.

Comment: I understood it..sorry I didn't not notice that I typed incorrectly there in those sentences.

Comment: Ok, something I understood now. You meant characteristic functions; yes, the projections in $C(X)$ are the characteristic functions. They correspond exactly with the $n$-tuples of $1$ and $0$ in $\mathbb C^n$.